# How to remove Web Tab Double Scroll Bar?

Tags: community, web-tab

I have created a "full page width" web tab with a URL but when I load the page it is showing double scroll bar as below. I do not want to adjust the "Content Frame Height (pixels)" manually as it is not dynamic. Anyway I can fix this?

[image]